# Is there a way to map columns that are not fixed name and position

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using CsvHelper and now struggling with the CSV format that have header name and number of columns is not fixed, for example

columnA, columnB, columnC, name_Your_name, name_His_name

also format can be

columnA, columnB, columnC, option1, option2, name_Will, name_John

columnA, columnB, columnC, option1, name_Anna, name_Peter

The option1, option2, option3,... is optional.
Sometimes the csv has more option4,5,6...

I'm reading the header with Class Map and index but cannot solve this.

Because of the name_Your_name column name is not fixed, so I assign Index = 4 but if there are option1, option2,... appear before, the index won't be correct.

I want to find the index of columns name_Your_name, name_His_name (name_Will, name_John, name_Anna...), is there any solution about this?

Thank you

```
Map(m => m.option1).Name("option1").Optional();
Map(m => m.option2).Name("option2").Optional();
Map(m => m.name_1).Index(4).Optional();
Map(m => m.name_2).Index(5).Optional();

When csv file does not have cols option1, option2 then the Index is 4
When csv file have cols option1, option2 then the Index is 6
```

Comment: Well the most simple way would be to have a `DefaultNameIndex` and add the occurances of the string `option` in the first row of the file. Is there anything that prohibits doing this?

Comment: Can you give me an example of DefaultNameIndex use

Comment: I'm talking about a normal integer variable that you count up. In this case you start with `var nameIndex = 4` and then have something like `nameIndex += OptionCount(headerRow);` with `private int OptionCount(string headerRow){...}`

Comment: who defines the column order in CSV? is it possible for you to change the order of the columns in CSV File?

Comment: the csv format is defined by third party so I dont think can change the order of columns

Answer (score 0):

I changed to use another way that is using dynamic object instead of using ClassMap, I saw the pattern columns have prefix name_ so I get all columns name_ and use the

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in row)
        {
            //this will get column name and index
        }
```